# What is wrong here? PLY in Python problem

Tags: python, ply

Here is my code:

```
import ply.lex as lex
import re

tokens = (
    'STRING', 'INT', 'BOOL', 'IF', 'ELIF', 'ELSE', 'WHILE',
    'FOR', 'FUNCTION', 'NEWLINE', 'WHITESPACE', 'PLUS', 'MINUS',
    'MULTIPLY', 'DIVIDE', 'COMMENT', 'COMMA', 'DOT', 'DDOT', 'IGNORE'
)
string       = r'[_a-zA-Z0-9\w]*'
t_STRING     = r'[_a-zA-Z0-9]\w*'
t_INT        = r'd+'
t_BOOL       = r'true|false'
t_IF         = r'if'
t_ELIF       = r'elif'
t_ELSE       = r'else'
t_WHILE      = r'while'
t_FOR        = r'for'
t_FUNCTION   = r'func' + string
t_NEWLINE    = r'\n+'
t_WHITESPACE = r' \r\t\f'
t_PLUS       = r'+'
t_MINUS      = r'-'
t_MULTIPLY   = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE     = r'/'
t_COMMENT    = r'#|//' + string
t_COMMA      = r','
t_DOT        = r'.'
t_DDOT       = r':'
t_IGNORE     = r' \r\t\f'

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

def t_error(t):
    print('ERROR: %s' % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex(reflags = re.UNICODE | re.DOTALL)

data = '''
if true:
    1 / 1
'''

lexer.input(data)

while True:
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok:
        break
    print(tok)
```

But the IDLE gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid regular expression for rule 't_PLUS'. nothing to repeat at position 11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Leha\Lang\parser.py", line 39, in <module>
    lexer = lex.lex(reflags = re.UNICODE | re.DOTALL)
  File "C:\Users\Leha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ply\lex.py", line 909, in lex
    raise SyntaxError("Can't build lexer")
SyntaxError: Can't build lexer
```

Comment: `+` has special meaning in regex. Try escaping it `t_PLUS = r'\\+'`. Note the double-\, also for multiply. Also, I think it should be `t_INT = r'\d+'`

Comment: @tobias_k: It's a raw string literal. You don't need to double the backslash and it won't work if you do. TIAS.